# How can I combine Flutter & Dart List with Class Property?

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class MonthModel {
  String? title;
  Months? months;

  MonthModel({this.title, this.months});
}

class Months {
  bool? january;
  bool? february;
  bool? march;
  bool? april;
  Months({this.january, this.february, this.march, this.april});
}

List<MonthModel> selectedMonths = [
  MonthModel(title: "January", months: Months(january: true)),
  MonthModel(title: "February", months: Months(february: true)),
];
```

January and February are included in the list. How can I convert to Months class based on the months added in the list?

I have to have Months(january: true, february: true) propertyed class.

Example json output

```json
    "months" : {
     "january": true,
     "february": true
    }
```

Comment: Can you recheck the edit, I am not getting about `Months(january: true, february: true);`

Comment: Sorry I am not understanding the question, Can you describe a little more what are you expecting from where

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I will create the selected months in the list in the Months class and convert them to json.

Comment: Are you trying to update the `selectedMonths` list like ` MonthModel(title: "January", months: Months(january: true,february: true)),`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh No, combining them into one separate class. The true state of January and February in the selectedMonths list in the Months class.

Comment: use https://app.quicktype.io/  for making model.

Comment: Why would you design your `Months` class this way?  If it has multiple `bool` members that are not independent, you should be using an `enum` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want somthing like

```dart
void main() {
  List<MonthModel> selectedMonths = [
    MonthModel(title: "January", months: Months(january: true)),
    MonthModel(title: "February", months: Months(february: true)),
  ];

  Months months = Months();

  for (final m in selectedMonths.map((e) => e.months).toList()) {
    if (m != null && m.january == true) {
      months.january = true;
    }
    if (m != null && m.february == true) {
      months.february = true;
    }
    if (m != null && m.march == true) {
      months.march = true;
    }
    if (m != null && m.april == true) {
      months.april = true;
    }
  }

  print(months.toString()); 
   ///Months(january: true, february: true, march: null, april: null)
}
```